# How can I take an entry from tkinter and print it in a txt document?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want what I get from function Sighnup and put it in 'Users.txt' and any tips in shortening TK code? I'm new to TK so any tips or tricks wpould be nice too!:) Oh and this is a program for an app my friend is making so I need it to work very well This is ~1/2 the code so i might need more help. Don't worry this is only one of the windows I have a login  window too. I know there is two Sighnup functions but it works well so i'm keeping it that way.When I do the (ent.get()) it prints it on the shell not the txt but It made the txt file but won't write in it.

```
import tkinter
def Sighnup():
    window2 = tkinter. Tk()
    def Quit2 ():
        window2.destroy()
    def Sighnup():
        open ('Users.txt','w')
        (ent.get())
        (ent2.get())
        (ent3.get())
        (ent4.get())
        (ent5.get())
        window2.destroy()
    window2.geometry("195x135")
    window2.title("Sighnup")
    window2.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
    lbl= tkinter.Label(window2, text="First Name:")
    lbl2= tkinter.Label(window2, text="Last Name:")
    lbl3= tkinter.Label(window2, text="Email:")
    lbl4=  tkinter.Label(window2, text="Username:")
    lbl5= tkinter.Label(window2, text="Password:")
    ent= tkinter.Entry(window2)
    ent2= tkinter.Entry(window2)
    ent3= tkinter.Entry(window2)
    ent4= tkinter.Entry(window2)
    ent5= tkinter.Entry(window2)
    btn= tkinter.Button(window2, text="Submit", command=Sighnup)
    btn2= tkinter.Button(window2, text="Quit", command=Quit2)
    lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)
    ent.grid(row=0, column=1)
    lbl2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    ent2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    lbl3.grid(row=2, column=0)
    ent3.grid(row=2, column=1)
    lbl4.grid(row=3, column=0)
    ent4.grid(row=3, column=1)
    lbl5.grid(row=4, column=0)
    ent5.grid(row=4, column=1)
    btn2.grid(row=5, column=1)
    btn.grid(row=5, column=0)
    window2.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to print in a file or you want to show an input window?

Comment: I wanted the entry to be recorded in a .txt but I found a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just opening a file doesn't make output go there, you need to write to it:

```
fout = open('Users.txt', 'w')
fout.write(ent.get())
...
```

Or better, use a context manager

```
with open('Users.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(ent.get())
```

As far as suggestions to clean things up, I would use loops to create the widgets and lists to store them.